# Configure Nginx to redirect all 404 errors to default nginx error page

Tags: nginx

I have a working application on a docker container on an EC2 instance and an ALB in front of it

the application is listening on port **8080**, so to access the application from the browser **http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}:8080/app**

now i installed Nginx on the same EC2 instance to redirect any 404 error to the default nginx error page

i did the following configuration

```
server {
listen       80;
listen       [::]:80;
server_name  _;

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
}
```

when for example i try to access **http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}/errorpage** i get the error page from Nginx

but when i try **http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}:8080** i get the application error page

and when **http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}:8080/app/errorpage** i get redirected to http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}:8080/app home page

what i want is if any incorrect page or 404 error comes on **http://{{ec2_instance_public_ip}}:8080/app/** gets redirected to Nginx error page

i guess i need to configure that if i got an 404 error i got redirected first to port 80 (Nginx port) but i dont know how

can you please help?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to configure error pages easier than nginx in my case.

I used AWS cloudfront to configure my error pages

you may refer to this URL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages-procedure.html